# Executing VBAscript from Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

I am in need of some help in regards to win32com.client. I have the code working as far as creating the macro from Python and using Excel but I would like this code to also run the vbascript.

Thank you guys for all of your wonderful feedback!

```
import pyodbc

import win32com.client as win32

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
ss = xl.Workbooks.Add()
sh = ss.ActiveSheet

xlmodule = ss.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)  # vbext_ct_StdModule

sCode = '''Sub Download_Standard_BOM()
'Initializes variables
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Network Library=dbmssocn;Password=********;User ID=*******;Initial Catalog=**;Data Source=*************;"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString

    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    StrQuery = "SELECT * FROM car_search WHERE shop_id = *******"

    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

    Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
End Sub'''

xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode)
```

Comment: [xlwings](http://xlwings.org/) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Excel's `Application.Run` method:

```
xl.Run "Download_Standard_BOM"
```

**EDIT**
If you need to refer to ADO, then you can either use late-binding, like this:

```
Dim cnn As Object 'ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As Object 'ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Or, use early binding and add a reference to the VBA Project:

```
ss.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}", 2, 8
```

Comment: thank you very much that does seem to try and execute it. However, now I receive the "User-defined type not defined" which I believe is because there is an object that isn't being referenced. If you don't mind my follow up question would be how do I add references when executing from Python?

Comment: Is there a way to call out references for my macro within Python?

Comment: Thank you ThunderFrame for the awesome help, I'm sooo close to wrapping this up, I've called out all of my references that I need but I'm still receiving a user-defined error and debug is pointing to this piece of code.
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As Object: Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String

More specifically the ADODB.Recordset but I have 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset referenced....any ideas?